# expected type-specifier before error c++

Tags: c++, punteros, herencia, polimorfismo, lenguaje-compilado

me sale un error al compilar que no entiendo, estoy implementando la hormiga de Langton usando herencia y polimormismo, al crear un puntero a una clase que define un tipo de hormiga con unas características especiales.

```
Estos son los errores que me salen:

error: expected type-specifier before ‘HormigaI’
           Hormiga *a = new HormigaI(ancho,alto);
                            ^
In file included from hormigaI.cpp:2:0:
hormigaI.hpp:7:31: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 class HormigaI: public Hormiga{
```

Este es el código de donde sale el primer error:

```
for(int i=0;i<numhormigas;i++){
    Hormiga *a = new HormigaI(ancho,alto);
    vechormigas.push_back(a);
}
```

`Hormiga` es la clase base y `HormigaI` es la clase derivada.

Que es lo que me causa el segundo error, refiriéndose a esa línea de código:

`class HormigaI: public Hormiga{`

Se agradece ayuda

Gracias

Comment: @AER, has sobrecargado `HormigaI` en `Hormiga`?

Comment: Te falta poner la declaración de ambas clases y los includes que tienes en el fichero donde te aparecen los errores